How to install Omniverse plugins in Blender4.2 ？
I don't know how to get the Omniverse plugin and successfully install it to support the usd file that I use to import.
Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks you!
Here are the plugins that have been installed:


That is a third-party addon and the latest information about it appears to be available here although that's from last year (2023) and it may not have been updated to be compatible with Blender version 4. You'll have to contact the authors and see if they have updated it as we can't help with third-party addons..
